# MS Access Full Outer Join Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I understand that MS Access does not 'Full Outer Join' function. I would like to combine two database into 1 big database.

An example is as follow:

[image: Example]
In conclusion, I would like to have full outer join to combine all columns from two database into 1 big database. Please advise alternative for full outer join in Access.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91f97/2)

```
select column1a,column2,coulmn3,column4,columna,'' as columnb from table1
union all 
select column1b,column2,coulmn3,column4,'' as columna,columnb from table2
```

Comment: Why ' ' instead of NULL?

Comment: becaue it will provide blank value instead of null as @jLeaner wants in expected result

Comment: By using union all, additional columns from table 2 will returned an error saying the number of columns in the 2 selection table do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you want a `UNION`.

```
SELECT Column1A as Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, ColumnA, NULL AS ColumnB
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1B, Column2, Column3, Column4, NULL, ColumnB
FROM Table2;
```

Comment: By using union all, additional columns from table 2 will returned an error saying the number of columns in the 2 selection table do not match.

Comment: I don't have MS Access on hand... maybe try `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`